# Is there a way to get number of chars in words in python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I want to get number of chars in words. Feature functions parameter in which the words are has to be np.array. Feature function should return feature matrix of shape(n,29). Following code returns dataframe.
Is there a way to do this more effectly.

```
def feature(a):
    chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzäö-"
    charlist = []
    for i in chars:
        charlist.append(i)
    #test if char is in the word and append to list1
    list1 = []
    for i in charlist:
        for j in a:
            
            list1.append(len(re.findall(i, j)))
    #divide list to chunks by char       
    l = np.array_split(np.array(list1),29)
    arr = np.array(l)
    arr = arr.T
    df = pd.DataFrame(arr, index = a, columns = charlist)
       
    return df

rndwords = []
for i in range(6):
    rndwords.append(''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_lowercase, k = 5)) )
array = np.asarray(rndwords, dtype=np.str)
feature(array)
```

Comment: why `'äö'` but not `'üß'` ?

Comment: why not `charlist = list(chars)` instead of the for loop?

Comment: why not `list1.append(a.count(i))`  instead of len(re.findall(..)) ?

Comment: Would all words be of the same length?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood your question correctly here, but are you just after the number of characters in the given word  for `chars`?

If so, it just might be as simple as `length = len(chars)`.
This would of course only give you the length of the word, but as you're after characters, that's really what you want...

You might want to be a bit more clear in your question. If you want to count all letters:

```
chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzäö-"
for i in  chars:
    count += 1
    current += i
    if current == chars :
        print(count)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can shorten this by using collections.Counter and avoid some numpy transpositions as well:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import random
import string
from collections import Counter 

def feature (a):
    chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzäö-"
    features = []
    for j in a:
        c = Counter()
        c.update({x: 0 for x in chars})
        c.update(j)
        features.append(c.values())

    df = pd.DataFrame(features, index = a, columns = list(chars))

    return df


rndwords = []
for i in range(6):
    rndwords.append(''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_lowercase, k = 5)) )
array = np.asarray(rndwords, dtype=np.str)

print(feature(array))
```

Output

```
       a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h  i  j  k  l  m  n  o  p  q  r  s  t  u  v  w  x  y  z  ä  ö  -
tidhv  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
fyafk  1  0  0  0  0  2  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0
gtxbf  0  1  0  0  0  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0
utwjk  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0
qknmw  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  1  1  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0
llkms  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  2  1  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```